# CASE when EXISTS (SELECT ...) seems to always returns true

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to test if a table exists. If it exists, I need to get the rowcount of that table, else I need to set the rowcount value to NULL.

Here is a snippet of the query I'am  using  :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
    -- TABLE A does not exists
        WHEN EXISTS (Select TABLE_NAME from ALL_TABLES where TABLE_NAME ='A') 
            THEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS."A") 
            ELSE NULL
        END AS TABLE_count
FROM dual;
```

When executing this query, I get the following error message :

```
SQL Error [942] [42000]: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

It seems that even if the EXISTS returns 0 rows, the THEN clause is always executed instead of going into the ELSE clause.

I don't understand the behavior here.
Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: I think the problem may be with `SYS."A"`.  Are you sure this is correct?  Can you run that count query in isolation successfully?

Comment: yes it runs fine with an existing table between the double quotes

Comment: But I didn't ask about any existing table, l asked if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS."A"` runs fine?

Comment: No it gives an error because the table does not exists

Comment: Check the answer by @Maxim below, who I think caught on to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this in pure sql since the query is parsed as a whole, including the section `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SYS."A"`
So if the table `SYS."A"` is absent then the whole query fails the parsing.

The alternative is to use pl/sql. You create a function that counts rows if table exists and if not - returns null.

Consider the following example:

```
create or replace function get_table_count(sTableName varchar2)
return number
is
  iCount number;
begin
  for c in (
    select null
    from   ALL_TABLES 
    where  TABLE_NAME = sTableName
  ) loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||sTableName into iCount;
    return iCount;
  end loop;
  return null;
end;
/

select get_table_count('DUAL') c1, get_table_count('ABSENT_TABLE') c2  from dual
```

returns

```
C1 C2
1  (null)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. It runs fine with MySQL so does MySQL and Oracle have different query parsing methods  ?

Comment: Oracle and MySQL have many distinctions. So when you migrate from one db to another - you should carefully test your code, almost probably you will have to rewrite part of your code.

Comment: Right answer. Also found the doc about it : https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_sqlproc.htm#GUID-EBB3A725-BF76-4B7C-A3A0-1D8CE20EFF7C